# ReactNative - How to get activity instance starting from version 0.29

Tags: android, android-activity, react-native

I am writing my own ViewManager which does need to get activity instance. Before version 0.29 it was straight forward, but after RN@0.29 [breaking changes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.29.0) I can't find a way to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Next React Native version will have the `reactContext.getCurrentActivity()` method exposed publicly rather than just being available when extending `ReactContextBaseJavaModule`.

Relevant commit: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/760656461197605ee26769ed73989f78e4753038

**Update**: [I've just confirmed](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9029#issuecomment-236191005) that this change will be cherry-picked into 0.31 and will land in few days.

Comment: Good, should be released in few days. Thank you.